# I cant start an emulator in Android Studio. Keep getting The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_30 was killed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have tried several things. I have reinstalled HAXM, I have reinstalled devices in AVD manager, deleted them, reinstalled SDK platforms, restarted my pc. Nothing helps.

Even when I add a new device I get the same error. Creating a new project gives the same error.

Is there anything I can do to get this error gone? Will reinstalling android studio help?

This error first occured when I wiped the data from one of my devices. Ever since no emulator has worked ever again.

If you need more info, let me know. I need the emulator to work.

Comment: Did you check if your Virtualization Technology (VT-x) is enabled or not on your pc?

Comment: I got it to work, I removed all avd folders in my .android folder

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem for a long time. I don't know what is the reason. But you can :

1. Use lower version of android in emulator
2. Don't start emulator directly, start emulator through cold boot.[recommend](for any android version)

Answer (score 0):

De-select Android Emulator in

Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools

Google reverted back to the previous version. If you de-select the new one and press on Apply, you will see the old one ready to be downloaded.

That fixed the issue for me.